# Can the components created by a Robe of Components be saved?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic, spell-components

Can spell components created by a [robe of components](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-of-components) be saved to be used in the future? The only condition I see on the robe itself is that they do not leave the spellcaster. Can this be used to stock up specific spell ingredients over the course of a long period of time?

Answer (score 4):

> The robe functions as a spell component pouch, providing any spell components or focuses that are necessary for the wearer’s spellcasting.

The robe only produces components and focuses that are necessary for spellcasting. You need to be casting a spell for it to produce the components and focuses needed for that spell, so you can't conjure, say, 50gp of diamond dust.

You could keep the focuses, as long as they never leave your person.

Comment: Im not sure I follow your logic.  "You need to be casting a spell for it to produce the components and focuses needed for that spell" - How are you inferring this? Dont you need the component to begin casting the spell? Meaning you need to create the material component before you cast? "To cast a spell, you must be able to... manipulate the material components" You cant manipulate components that you dont have, therefor you cant start casting.

Comment: However it does sound like you believe that the things it does create, will last forever as long as it doesn't leave your person and they aren't consumed by the spell. So that does indirectly answer my question.

Comment: The text says "providing [...] that are _necessary_ for [...] spellcasting". If you're not casting a spell, no components are _necessary_. As soon as you start casting fireball, a guano ball is necessary to cast it, so the robe provides it. About how long it lasts, RAW it's not written it disappears but neither anything says you can't sell the iron in iron walls, but at that point you're not playing the game anymore, you're cheesing out money.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct given how the item is written; I do however, think the item was written poorly and this is how it should be run. On my first point, they did not say something along the lines of "when you cast a spell", but "for the wearer's spellcasting" which is more open-ended. Any number of things could be needed for your spellcasting, but very specific things are needed for you to cast a spell.

Comment: I think based on the "if it leaves your person" line, that implies that it doesnt generate the components as you cast the spell, because then you wouldnt have a chance to give them away. 

Furthermore, in terms of balance, your paying 5000, for 50g of materials a day, which would take 100 days to pay for itself. (a long time in most campaigns). The benefit being you dont need to be as stringent as to which materials you buy. Another downside being since it only generates 50g chunks a day, any spell that calls for a single component with more than 50g value cannot be cast.

Comment: It can probably be run either way and not affect balance significantly.